# Android Bluetooth LE: get Gatt of already connected Device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Short version:**
Is there a way to get the Gatt, knowing the device, and knowing this device is already connected?

**Detailed:**
I'm working on BLE devices whose address I know.
Before reading a characteristic, I'd like to test if the device isn't already connected.
Seem's it has to be done throught `BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices()`
So I wrote a little isConnected() method:

```
fun isConnected(address: String): Boolean {
  val connDev = bluetoothLEHandler.bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT)
  connDev.forEach{ if(it.address == address ) return true }
  return false
}
```

After checking for existing connexion, if answer is yes, I'd like to use corresponding Gatt:

```
if(isConnected(device.address)){//don't reconnect, just trigger connection callback
  onConnectionEstablished(/*here I need the gatt of the already connected device*/)
}
```

-> How can I get the Gatt, knowing the device, and knowing this device is connected?

-> Or am I trying to do something stupid, should I always use `device.connectGatt(...)` to get a Gatt, not even trying to check if not already connected?

-> Or should the situation never occur, because I should always have closed previous connection, even knowing there's a high probability I have to reconnect in instants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices() can be used to see if your device is connected. However when it comes to interacting with a remote GATT device, the more correct (at least more common) flow is to store the reference to the GATT device upon the initial connection to that device. Then whenever you want to interact with that device (read/write/notify, etc), you use the reference from the connection callback. [This link](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/) summarizes it well:-

> A successful connection attempt will see the onConnectionStateChange()
> callback happen with its status parameter set to GATT_SUCCESS and
> newState parameter set to BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED. At this
> point, it’s crucial to store a reference to the BluetoothGatt object
> that is also provided by this callback. This will be the main
> interface through which we issue commands to the BLE device.

So in other words, you don't need to disconnect and reconnect again, or call device.connectGatt() on an existing connection, but rather use the GATT parameter that was returned as part of the [onConnectionStateChage() callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: You can also simply store the (same) reference returned by the connectGatt method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll store the reference(s) to connected gatt(s) myself then... but I thought it would have made sense for BluetoothManager, when already keeping track of open connections, to also keep track of corresponding gatts. Without requiring any overhead  of referencing them myself... I must be toooo lazy ;-)

Comment: Note that multiple apps can have their own gatt objects, but the manager will tell you if any app has a connection open for a device.